# Whether Angular ui-router support different master layout pages(new Html Page) from nested view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-ui-router-extras, angular-router-loader

Today I have created  a  ThemeForest like a website with angular and mvc , So  I have  a login page, it will load the Dashboard page, In the dashboard page have lots of icons, So i click the Icons , it will load the complete different layout page for every template.

here is my Question.

**

1. I need to load an every new layout from current nested views. Don't
   want to load under the nested views?

2) And the view is not a partial view type and its a new HTML page with new css and Js files reference from current file.

3) I don't want to load the current Js files in new Html file.

**

Whether Angular js ui-Routing techniques works by using ui-view mentioned in the page.So in the page i have click the icon, need to load different master page,So right now what happen  is the master page is loaded under the dashboard page. It will be support by angular routing or not.

So i have created a  sample demo:

$stateProvider

```
        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        // nested list with custom controller
        .state('home.list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: 'Ecommmerce-Website.html',

        })

        // nested list with just some random string data
        .state('home.paragraph', {
            url: '/paragraph',
            template: 'I could sure use a drink right now.'
        })

        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            views: {
                '': { templateUrl: 'partial-about.html' },
                'columnOne@about': { template: 'Look I am a column!' },
                'columnTwo@about': { 
                    templateUrl: 'table-data.html',
                    controller: 'scotchController'
                }
            }

        });

});
```

It is the startup page:

Here I am loading the Dashboard page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <!-- CSS (load bootstrap) -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            .navbar { border-radius:0; }
        </style>

        <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <!-- apply our angular app to our site -->
    <body ng-app="routerApp">



    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

This is the root router template view loaded in above html.

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">


    <a ui-sref=".list" class="btn btn-primary">Ecommerce Websites</a>
    <a ui-sref=".paragraph" class="btn btn-danger">Hotels Websites</a>

</div>

<div ui-view></div>
```

another master page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust if needed) */
    .row.content {height: 1500px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height: auto;} 
    }
  </style>
    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="routerApp">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav">
      <h4>John's Blog</h4>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Family</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Photos</a></li>
      </ul><br>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Blog..">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <h4><small>RECENT POSTS</small></h4>
      <hr>
      <h2>I Love Food</h2>
      <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Post by Jane Dane, Sep 27, 2015.</h5>
      <h5><span class="label label-danger">Food</span> <span class="label label-primary">Ipsum</span></h5><br>
      <p>Food is my passion. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <br><br>

      <h4><small>RECENT POSTS</small></h4>
      <hr>
      <h2>Officially Blogging</h2>
      <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Post by John Doe, Sep 24, 2015.</h5>
      <h5><span class="label label-success">Lorem</span></h5><br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <hr>

      <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <br><br>

      <p><span class="badge">2</span> Comments:</p><br>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
          <img src="bandmember.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h4>Anja <small>Sep 29, 2015, 9:12 PM</small></h4>
          <p>Keep up the GREAT work! I am cheering for you!! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
          <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <h4>John Row <small>Sep 25, 2015, 8:25 PM</small></h4>
          <p>I am so happy for you man! Finally. I am looking forward to read about your trendy life. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <br>
          <p><span class="badge">1</span> Comment:</p><br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
              <img src="bird.jpg" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
              <h4>Nested Bro <small>Sep 25, 2015, 8:28 PM</small></h4>
              <p>Me too! WOW!</p>
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the plunker Demo:
http://embed.plnkr.co/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7/preview:

Answer (score 1):

You have to make some changes in your code to achieve your requirement.

**I used ui-router multiple views to achieve this** [here is a documentation for it](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/multiple-named-views)

1) In **app.js**, Change your states to,

```
 $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
           views: {
                '': { templateUrl: 'partial-home.html' },
                'header': { templateUrl: 'tplheader.html', },
                'footer': { 
                    templateUrl: 'tplfooter.html',

                }
            }
        })

        // nested list with custom controller
        .state('list', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
            }
        })

        // nested list with just some random string data
        .state('paragraph', {
            url: '/paragraph',
            template: 'I could sure use a drink right now.'
        })

        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            views: {
                '': { templateUrl: 'partial-about.html' },
                'columnOne@about': { template: 'Look I am a column!' },
                'columnTwo@about': { 
                    templateUrl: 'table-data.html',
                    controller: 'scotchController'
                }
            }

        });

});
```

Check, change `home.list` to `.state('list')` and `home.paragraph` `.state('paragraph' )`

2) Second, **partial-home.html**

change `ui-sref=".list"` to `ui-sref="list"` and `ui-sref=".paragraph"` to `ui-sref="paragraph"`

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The Homey Page</h1>
    <p>This page demonstrates <span class="text-danger">nested</span> views.</p>

    <a ui-sref="list" class="btn btn-primary">List</a>
    <a ui-sref="paragraph" class="btn btn-danger">Paragraph</a>

</div>

<div ui-view></div>
```

3)  In **index.html**

```
<body ng-app="routerApp">

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tplheader.html">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</script>

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
<div class="container">
  <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="tplfooter.html">
  <div class="text-center">
    <p>A tutorial by <a href="http://scotch.io" target="_blank">scotch.io</a></p>
    <p>View the tutorial: <a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router" target="_blank">AngularJS Routing using UI-Router</a></p>
</div>
</script>



</body>
```

[**HERE IS THE CHANGED PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wETfcMbGBTWrQXXp4RTk?p=preview)

Comment: Routing working properly, But i have to load completly new layout its not working, I need the completely new layout when clicking the list or paragraph, I don't want to load under the menu icons also. if it is not possible means i will go for another approach instead of angular routing.

Comment: check the  plunker now

Comment: Glad to help you. you can accept my answer, if you find it useful.

Comment: This Solution will only works inside the layout but in my case need to load new Html layout which means it contains same js reference or different js reference and new css file, I don't want to load old css styles in new layout. Routing works inside the single page application, in my case when click the button , it will load new layout file html ,body and with new head tag.

Comment: you can include js and css files depending on the current route

Comment: Ok, I will try, if it is not working means create a Github, thanks for your prompt replies because I don't want to given the <script type=" text/ng-template" id="tplheader.html"> name for a particular portion because my layout is completely different from header to body. https://plnkr.co/edit/6tFZGS2Nt1FYZyaR5mLz?p=preview. Rignt now i have achieved the concept using js redirection method.

Comment: See the updated plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/VGxqRtygHkY1RU0OzKJd?p=preview In the plunker , i have index.html use <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstra‌​p.min.css"> and Ecommerce website.html use <link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/…; this version css same for js and override some functionlity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145121/discussion-between-sravan-and-mohamed-sahir).

Comment: Ok, I will create a GitHub of my layout structure come for a chat. thank you